# Export import calibre database

Tags: export, ebook, calibre

I am using calibre for my e-book management software. Is there any way to export import whole database (Tags, tiles, authors list), so that I can import to another machine?

Comment: this is exactly what you want http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=118556

Answer (score 8):

If you wish the new database to totally replace the old, just replace the entire folder that you specified when you ran the welcome wizard.

If you wish to **add** ebooks from one computer to another, you could use the [calibredb](http://calibre-ebook.com/user_manual/cli/calibredb.html) command-line interface to the calibre database, found in my case in `C:\Program Files\Calibre2\calibredb.exe`. However, while it can do export, I haven't found any import option.

A funny idea might be to use the calibredb option of `restore_database` :

> Restore this database from the
>   metadata stored in OPF files in each
>   directory of the calibre library. This
>   is useful if your metadata.db file has
>   been corrupted.
>
> WARNING: This command completely
>   regenerates your database. You will
>   lose all saved searches, user
>   categories, plugboards, stored
>   per-book conversion settings, and
>   custom recipes. Restored metadata will
>   only be as accurate as what is found
>   in the OPF files.

This will require manually copying the additional sub-folders of the calibre directory from the source to the target computer (but not metadata.db), then regenerate the database using the restore_database command.

Answer (score 5):

The *calibredb add* command adds one or more entire book files to the database, from e-book files or one or more directories.

The *calibredb export* command "saves all formats of the book, its cover and metadata (in an opf file)," which does not sound like what you want.

To export bibliographic information, it looks like you can use the *calibredb catalog* command, which allows you to save a set of fields as a CSV, XML, or other format file. See the reference page at http://bit.ly/rC15wz.

Answer (score 3):

Both answers above missed the point completely!

To export your library (with your tags, authors list, titles, etc) to another computer simply copy to the new computer your whole library folder (including all subfolders and two files generated by calibre and placed at the "root" of the library folder, the first being named "database.db" and the other a file with the extension ".json" and with stores all the information about that library).

Then run calibre and add the library by right-clicking the library icon and selecting to add a new library and voilà! You now completely exported your whole library to another computer.